# Terraform Error for AWS route53 zone - no matching Route53Zone found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, terraform

I am creating a AWS route53 zone.

Here is my code. create zone

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "kubetest" {
  name = "kubetest.com"
}
```

Then using data to get details

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "selected" {
  name = "kubetest.com"
}

output "ns" {
  value = "${data.aws_route53_zone.selected.name_servers}"
```

but getting error when do `terrafrom plan`.

```
Error: Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:

* data.aws_route53_zone.selected: 1 error(s) occurred:

* data.aws_route53_zone.selected: data.aws_route53_zone.selected: no matching Route53Zone found
```

If i do create first zone only and then add data working fine, in this case i have to run `terraform plan` 2 times and comments and un-comment  code for `data` section.
i have checked [no matching Route53Zone found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631966/no-matching-route53zone-found-terraforms-route53-data-source-is-not-recogniz) and others but same error.

Comment: You need to look into depends_on and make sure it's created before the lookup happens.. Is this all in the same module or directory? If so then you don't need the data lookup you can just use the resource

Comment: If all code in same file,  I heard terraform  take care everything like dependency as well. Let me check depends_on too.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the data lookup in the same file if you create it there also. Just use the resource. data source lookups are great for things created outside of terraform or in another terraform run. For example, one terraform run from a networking from might create the VPC/subnets/routes/etc. Your run might build on top of it so you use a data source lookup to find the subnets to use.

Just do this

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "kubetest" {
  name = "kubetest.com"
}

output "ns" {
  value = "${aws_route53_zone.kubetest.name_servers}"
}
```

Comment: I agree, but i need to ```data``` because i am using for different purpose And we can use data in same file as well if require. i guess ```depends_on```  might  help in my case.

Comment: no you can use `${aws_route53_zone.kubetest.name_servers}` in the same run as long as things aren't in modules

Comment: Will create module so i need  ```data```

Comment: ```depends_on``` is working but then ```cloudflare_record.aws-ns-record: value of 'count' cannot be computed``` i found its known issue. if you have any workaround please let me know.